# How to view result of phonegap in different platform(ios,android,windows)

Tags: android, ios, eclipse, windows, cordova

I have created android project in eclipse, added cordova.js and cordova-2.9.0.jar file and created index.html to develop mobile application. On running this app, it by default  runs in android emulator.
How can i see output of other platforms like ios,windows??

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make your question more clear to us.

Comment: @Trupti have you read the documentation about exporting your PhoneGap project ? There are some [tutorials](https://www.scirra.com/tutorials/71/how-to-make-native-phone-apps-with-construct-2-and-phonegap) around the Internet as well.

Comment: @avk I will try best to explain my question in detail.

Comment: @Raptor Thanks, i have created phonegap/cordova app in eclipse, i want to know weather eclipse or cordova it self provide any feature to run same in different platforms without any setups

Answer (score 0):

Lets work through your questions which is not even very detailed.

First of all, update your cordova. 2.9.0 is an old version. To do so just run

**Mac:**

```
sudo npm update -g cordova
```

**Windows: (run cmd as administrator)**

```
npm update -g cordova
```

After you did that, i would recommend you to read the very detailed documentation of cordova which can be found over here: [Cordova Documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/).

Finished with that? Good, then you should know now, that there is now way to deploy an iOS App from your Windows Computer to your iPad or iPhone. This is only possible on a mac. Because the applications are just "rendered Websites" you can open up the `index.html` files inside your browser.

cue browser... there is a platform, which is called browser. This is a much better than the normal browsers. You will find a documentation for that over here: [Browser Documentation and Information](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/09/24/Browser-as-a-platform-for-your-PhoneGapCordova-apps). It can be installed via

```
cordova platform add browser
```